# Why is the ampersand retained in this translation?

Tags: traducción

On my bag of Pumpkin seeds (from Bulgaria, which I like a lot more than other pumpkin seeds, which are bigger and flatter), It has the English (not Bulgarian) description:

```
Pumpkin Seeds Roasted & Salted
```

...which is translated thus:

```
Semillas de Calabaza Tostadas & Saladas
```

Why would the "&" be retained? In English it makes sense, because that single character replaces three characters ("and") but in the case of the Spanish it doesn't, as the word that the ampersand represents ("y") is a single character. Wouldn't this be a preferable translation:

```
Semillas de Calabaza Tostadas y Saladas
```

?

Comment: [&](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand) is a shortening of the Latin *et*, from which the Spanish [*y* is derrived](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=y). When you consider this, your question seems a bit backwards--why does English, which is *not* derived from Latin, use *&*? But that's a question for another site :)

Comment: Even the English name *ampersand* derives partly from latin (*and per se and*). Though you are right, @Flimzy, this is not a question for this forum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it'd be preferable as *y*.  Although *&* is certainly permissible in Spanish (in fact, the DRAE surprisingly still recognizes the full word *et* as a valid Spanish conjunction, although labeling it as *desusado*), when standing in for *y*, it's rarely used since *&* takes more time to type or write.  In older Spanish, you'd see it occasionally fill in for etcétera as *&cetera* or *&c.* (the latter of which sees some use in English).  In modern day Spanish, it's mainly used commercial, mostly I think to give a foreign flair.

The only time I'd ever see it necessary might be if there'd be a situation where, for instance, you have two people's surnames names and you want to make it clear there are two people rather than just one person with the conjunction *y* in between his/her surnames.  But that'd be such a rare circumstance (maybe multi-author parenthetical citations?) for confusion I can't even think of one off the top of my head, and frankly commas work just as nicely haha.

Comment: It's actually not that rare. It's commonly used for the name of partnerships, like a lawyer's office: `Feregrino & Villalobos`, for example.

Comment: @FranciscoZarabozo That's probably a good example of exactly that situation I mentioned :)  If a law office were *Feregrino y Villalobos*, you wouldn't know if it's one person or two.  Using *&* forces the two-person interpretation.